Add an extra equation to a linear system about the diagonals of a parallelogram
I am revisiting some basic elements of linear algebra and am going through the proof of the fact that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other using vectors.
I know a good way to do this is to prove that the mid points of the two diagonals are actually the same, by expressing them as linear combinations of the vectors of two adjacent sides.
However, this time I want to try a different approach, and unfortunately, I am stuck on this approach:

Considering the four triangles resulting from the division by the two diagonals, I have
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec{a} + \vec{d}_1 &= \vec{c}_1 \\
\vec{c}_1 + \vec{d}_2 &= \vec{b} \\
\vec{d}_1 + \vec{c}_2 &= \vec{b} \\
\vec{d}_2 + \vec{a} &= \vec{c}_2
\end{align*}
$$
I want to solve this linear system about $\vec{c}_1, \vec{c}_2, \vec{d}_1, \vec{d}_2$ to get $\vec{c}_1 = \vec{c}_2$ and $\vec{d}_1 = \vec{d}_2$.
However, it turned out that I have missed something, because the system can be reduced to:
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \vec{a} \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \vec{b} \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \vec{b} \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & \vec{a}
 \end{bmatrix}
\to
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \vec{b} \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & \vec{a} \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \vec{b} - \vec{a} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vec{0}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
, which is of rank 3 and cannot fully be solved for $\vec{c}_1, \vec{c}_2, \vec{d}_1, \vec{d}_2$.
I tried to add something like $\vec{c_1}+\vec{c_2} = \vec{a} + \vec{b}$ and $\vec{c_1}+\vec{c_2}+\vec{d_1}+\vec{d_2} = 2\vec{b}$, but they can all by deduced from the original linear system.
So I would like to ask what could be added to solve the system to finish my approach.
As @user376343 and @dmk pointed out, there are ways to prove that the two diagonals are not parallel, and thus we can simply use this fact and the 2nd and 3rd equations in the system to get the solution. Nevertheless, I still want to know if I can find an extra equation to add to the system so that it can work, because I think there should be one.

What is your start point? Do you ASSUME that the figure is a parallelogram?

@user376343 Yes, what I tried to prove is about a parallelogram.

I'll mention in passing: Your augmented matrix uses vectors in its last column rather than the coefficients on those vectors. If I've ever tried doing this, I don't recall, and so I'm not sure it would necessarily present an insurmountable issue; it seems it could start causing problems when you get a new vector, $b - a$, over there, though. In any case, it's not the way your system of equations (which is fine the way it is) would usually get translated :).

Beyond that, I wrote an answer and then reread your most recent comment. When you ask if there's a way to continue with "[your] approach", how would you describe that approach? After rereading @user376343's answer, it seemed a good continuation of what you'd done -- though perhaps not what you might have intended to do next.

@dmk So long as the vectors in the rightmost column have operations that have the same properties as those involved (addition and scalar multiplication) in the elementary row operations of matrix reduction, it should be fine. After all, they are not coefficients, but values that the unknown variables in the linear system may take.

@dmk, I have modified my post to restrict my question into asking if such an extra equation can be found that with it the system can be solved for those four vectors. Not sure if I should edit my title as well.

[Deleted comments since I'd forgotten to read your update.] What if you include the equations $c_2 = mc_1$ and $d_2 = nd_1$, for real numbers $m, n$? (Numbers you'll have to solve for.) Do those help you proceed in the way you want?

@dmk, on some thoughts, I think your suggestion is a promising direction! The vectors that satisfy my system might not be aligned with the diagonals at all (pick any point inside the parallelogram and connect it to the four vertices)! Probably I should stick to one unknown, instead of introducing two unknowns with two new equations. Like $\vec{c}_1 = k(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$ and $\vec{c}_2 = (1-k)(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$. But these two don't quite work, as they sum up to $c_1+c_2 = a+b$, which can be deduced from the original system, so they together only add one rank to the system. A little confused now

MSE saved my draft of an answer for a few days before losing it, so... For now: A question I posed in a deleted comment that should have remained: Would you describe your approach as attempting to obtain a matrix in RREF, thus yielding a full answer? Because it seems as though, at some point, we may need to step outside of that, observe something about linear independence and conclude that way -- much as user376343 did, and as I did with my now lost solution. (I believe I rewrote your original four equation as a homogeneous system in $a, b, c_1$ and $d_1$.)

Alternatively, it means starting over, but: Let $c=a+b$ and $d=-a+b$. Then there exist real numbers $k,l$ such that $a+kd=lc$, where $lc$ is the same as your $c_1$. It takes three lines or so to show that $k=l=1/2$.

@dmk After several tries, I think you are probably right. Although the vectors in the augmented matrix are good under those elementary row operations, it seems that the action of putting them into such a matrix loses some information, so I can't use a such a matrix only to get the desired solutions. For now, I will accept user376343's answer as a way to add extra information to my system, until in the future somehow I figure out exactly what is lost. And thank you for this discussion all along!

Subtracting the second and third vector equations, we get
$$\vec{c_1}-\vec{c_2}=\vec{d_1}-\vec{d_2}.$$
Since the LHS vector is collinear with one diagonal, while RHS with the other, the only possibility is
$$\vec{c_1}-\vec{c_2}=\vec{d_1}-\vec{d_2}=\vec{0}.$$

If I use this, then I have to prove that the two diagonals are never parallel as well. It might be obvious but not immediately available. Besides, if we know that they bisect each other, then we can express $\vec{c_1}, \vec{c_2}, \vec{d_1}, \vec{d_2}$ in terms of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$. There is only one more equation away from getting these solutions, and I really want to know what I missed.

@GuanyumingHe, are $a$ and $b$ parallel? And if these two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ aren't parallel, what can we say about them? Or, for that matter, what can we say about $c = a + b$ and $d = -a + b$?

@dmk, yes, by trying to solve $\vec{a} + \vec{b} = k(-\vec{a} + \vec{b})$ we can conclude that they are not parallel if $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are not parallel and non-zero. Thanks for this. Yet I still want to know if I can add an equation to the system to make my approach work. I will edit my question to reflect this.

@GuanyumingHe diagonals in a convex quadrilateral are secant.

@user376343, sorry, my geometry knowledge is poor, and I don't know what secant means. On Google I can only find "secant" about one line (a secant line), not about two lines.

@GuanyumingHe sorry, "secant" comes from french. Should be "intersecting".
